# probability of having an ace on each hand when dealing $52$ cards to $4$ hands

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question from DeGroot's book: "probability and statistics"

"Suppose that a deck of $52$ cards containing four aces is shuffled thoroughly
and the cards are then distributed among four players so that each player
receives $13$ cards. We shall determine the probability that each player will receive one ace."

I so far have $3$ methods to solve this problem, all of them yield the number provided in the book. Below is my $4$th method. Alas, it doesn't give the same answer:

Since the question doesn't concern which suit of ace goes to which hand, and the differences between remaining cards are irrelevant, I simplify the question as:

"Distribute $52$ cards containing $4$ A's and $48$ B's to $4$ piles so that each pile
receives $13$ cards. determine the probability that each pile will receive one A."

to solve this simplified question, I focus on distribution of the $4$ A's, then distribute the $48$ B's to $4$ piles to make each $13$-card pile:

1. there is only $1$ way to distribute $4$ A's to $4$ piles.
2. I summed up below sets of outcomes to compute the sample space:

number of combinations that one hand get all $4$ A's: $4$ 
number of combinations that one hand get 3 A's: $4\times3$
number of combinations that $2$ hands each get $2 $A's, the other $2$ hands get  0 A: 6
number of combinations that one hand get $2$ A's, two other hands each get $1$ A: $12$
number of combinations that each hand get $1$ A: $1$

So, here is the number:
$\frac{1}{35}=0.0286$
which is about $3.7$ time smaller chance than the "correct answer" ($0.1055$).

Why does this way of counting not work ?

Thanks!

P.S.

==================================

I think the first method given by the author partially applied this simplification: it doesn't distinguish different suit of aces.

the method is:
The number of possible different combinations of the four positions in the deck
occupied by the four aces is $\binom{52}{4}$. and there are exactly $13^4$ of combinations for each ace in each player's hand. the result is:

$$P=\frac{13^4}{\binom{52}{4}}= 0.1055$$

Answer (score 1):

Your simplification doesn't work. Without the simplification, there are $24$ ways to give each player an ace while there are four ways to give all aces to one person. Your simplification skews this relation, and thus the probability.

Comment: I'm aware of this. but the book stated that:
"If we have the choice between whether or not to count
the same elements in different orders as different outcomes, then we need to make
our choice and be consistent throughout the problem. If we count the same elements
in different orders as different outcomes when counting the outcomes in S, we must
do the same when counting the elements of E. If we do not count them as different
outcomes when counting S, we should not count them as different when counting E.". It suggest that it's ok as long as you use the same counting method for E and S.

Comment: as far as the question's requirement is concerned, it sounds a valid simplification.

Comment: "as far as the question's requirement is concerned, it sounds a valid simplification. "  It does?!?!?!?  Seriously?  There are 24 ways to distribute 4 cards to four different piles based on which ace goes to which piles but you equate those all.  So when you distribute all for cards to one hand why do you *then* distinguish which player gets it.  Shouldn't there be only one way?  Either a player gets them all or ... not?  And how can you justify the claim the likely hood of Bill getting 4ace is exactly the same as the liklihood of Sam getting 3 aces and Jill getting 1?

Comment: When it comes to simplification "sounding" like a valid simplification is not enough.  You must prove and demonstrate it is valid.  In math everything is invalid until proven valid.  Not the other way around

Comment: points taken. the fact is, the question doesn't distinguish the suit of ace and the same goes for the rest of the deck (non-ace's). and the order of the 13 cards doesn't matter. it only recognize aces and non-aces. and I think that's it. the assumption for the 3 "correct" answers I have is my eyes must always care both the number (A2..JQK) and suite of each combination of 13 cards, which is not a requirement of the question itself...I'm now suspecting those "correct" answers might not be actually correct.

Comment: as far as I understand, there is no way to validate a answer to a probability question other than  logical deduction from axioms. the likelihood of Bill getting 4 aces, the likelihood of Sam getting 3 aces and Jill getting 1 are calculated based on method counting...

Comment: @fleablood: I should qualify my previous words as: there are ways to validate counting questions (by hand, by computer, etc). as for "why do you then distinguish which player gets it", it does make sense to treat the players as identical. the different result is caused by different experiment setup -> different observation. the key thing needs to be understood is why we need to care about the suits of the card when counting. the question only care about ace and non-ace. I tend to assume that in this kind of questions, if you don't car about the difference, then the difference doesn't exist.

Comment: @fleablood: I finally get your point. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your are assuming that all the possibilities you list are equally probable.  This is not true.  There are about twice as many ways to distribute the remaining cards when each person gets an ace than when one person gets four aces.

Comment: thanks. but the book seemed to suggest that counting method doesn't matter as long as consistent counting method for E and S...(see page 53 of the book. I also quoted in the comment above)

Answer (score 1):

The first Arc can be placed anyhwere, the second only have 39 possible positions, the third 26, the last 13. Thus,
 the answer $\frac{52*39*26*13}{52*51*50*49}$.

Comment: this answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

It is much harder to determine the probability using the given approach :

The number of possibilities for the distributions are :

$4-0-0-0 : \frac{48!}{13!\cdot13!\cdot13!\cdot9!}\cdot 4$

$3-1-0-0 : \frac{48!}{13!\cdot13!\cdot12!\cdot10!}\cdot 12\cdot 4$

$2-2-0-0 : \frac{48!}{13!\cdot13!\cdot11!\cdot11!}\cdot 6\cdot 6$

$2-1-1-0 : \frac{48!}{13!\cdot12!\cdot12!\cdot11!}\cdot 12\cdot 12$

Just for completion :

$1-1-1-1 : \frac{48!}{12!\cdot12!\cdot12!\cdot12!}\cdot 24$

If you add the first $4$ of the above numbers and divide the sum by the total number of possibilities, you get the probability that not every player receives exactly one ace. The desired probability is $1$ minus that probability.

I will leave it as an exercise to find out how the numbers are determined.

Comment: OP knows the correct answer and has asked why his technique does not yield it.

Comment: if I understand correctly, your counting is based on these assumpitions:
1. suites matter
2. number matter
3. order matter

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the question below:

"spread 4 aces into 4 pile, so for each ace, it have 4 position to stand, the length of sample space will be 4*4*4*4. and only 1 way to get each position have one ace. the probability will be 1/4*4*4*4 = 0.00390625."

Comment: this answer is wrong.