probability that everyone receives exactly 1 king card
Using a deck of 52 cards, and 4 players, we randomly give 13 cards to each player.
What's the probability that each player receives exactly 1 king card? In total, there are 4 king cards.
My attempt: We must distribute the 4 king cards between 4 players. The other cards are irrelevant. Then, I compute the following two numbers:

The total number of assignments of the 4 cards to the players. The first card goes to a player (4 possibilities), the second to a player (4 possibilities), and so on. Hence, there are a total of $4^{4}$ assignments.

The number of assignments in which every player receives exactly 1 card. The first card goes to a player (4 possibilities), the second to ANOTHER player (3 possibilities), and so on. Hence, there are 4! possibilities.


Thus, my solution would be $\frac{4!}{4^{4}} = 0.09$.
However, this seems to be wrong, as the true solution is given to be 0.1055
Where does this reasoning go wrong? What's the correct reasoning?

Welcome to MSE. The following seems like a very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863210/probability-of-having-an-ace-on-each-hand-when-dealing-52-cards-to-4-hands?rq=1

You need to take account of the $52$ potential cards ($13$ each).

The possible distributions of the kings are not equally probable.  Getting one ace makes it slightly less likely that you'll get the next, as you only get so many cards.
