Probability of exactly 1 ace in each hand of 13 cards
I am attempting to find the probability that each hand of 13 cards from a deck of 52 cards contains exactly one ace. My approach is to use conditional probability. Below is my approach, and I would appreciate guidance as to what is specifically causing a wrong final answer
Let's define A, B, C, D as the events that the 1st hand has 1 ace, the 2nd hand has 1 ace, the 3rd hand has 1 ace, the 4th hand has 1 ace.
Then, we need P(ABCD) = P(A) * P(B/A) * P(C/AB) * P(D/ABC)
P(A) = 4 * $\binom{48}{12}$ / $\binom{52}{13}$
P(B/A) = 3 * $\binom{48}{12}$ / $\binom{51}{13}$ --> My logic here is that I only know the first player's hand has 1 ace. So there are 51 cards that are equally likely to be in the 2nd person's hand, hence the $\binom{51}{13}$ denominator. For the numerator, we have 3 aces left and can have any of the 48 non-aces in the hand with equal probability, of which we choose 12.
P(C/AB) = 2 * $\binom{48}{12}$ / $\binom{50}{13}$
P(D/ABC) = 1 * $\binom{48}{12}$ / $\binom{49}{13}$
Multiplying these gives me 0.02, which is not the correct answer of 0.105. I would appreciate anyone's help in correcting the mistake with this approach, thanks!

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863210/probability-of-having-an-ace-on-each-hand-when-dealing-52-cards-to-4-hands https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921486/a-deck-of-52-cards-is-divided-into-four-piles-of-13-cards-what-is-the-proba https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245893/probability-that-each-pile-of-cards-has-exactly-one-ace-different-solution-dif https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4895283/probability-that-everyone-receives-exactly-1-king-card https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521017

The easiest approach is place the aces one-by-one.

The Ace of Spades is in one of the hands with probability $\frac{52}{52}$
Given the position of the Ace of Spades, the Ace of Hearts is in one of the other three hands with probability $\frac{39}{51}$
Given the position of the Aces of Spades and Hearts in different hands, the Ace of Diamonds is in one of the other two hands with probability $\frac{26}{50}$
Given the position of the Aces of Spades, Hearts and Diamonds in different hands, the Ace of Clubs is in the remaining hand with probability $\frac{13}{49}$

Multiply these together and you get about $0.105498$.
As a check, you would hope this would be a little bigger than $\frac44\times \frac34\times \frac24\times \frac14=0.09375$. It is.

Using your method, there is a clear problem with your final $1 \times \binom{48}{12} / \binom{49}{13}$ as, given the other three hands each have exactly one ace, the fourth hand also has exactly one ace with probability $1$; you should have had $1 \times \binom{12}{12} / \binom{13}{13}$ as you had already allocated $39$ cards including $3$ aces to the previous hands. There are similar issues with your second and third conditional probabilities.
Your multiplication of probabilities should have been
$\Big(4 \times \binom{48}{12} / \binom{52}{13}\Big) \times \Big(3 \times \binom{36}{12} / \binom{39}{13}\Big) \times \Big(2 \times \binom{24}{12} / \binom{26}{13}\Big) \times  \Big(1 \times \binom{12}{12} / \binom{13}{13} \Big)$
and this too would have given you about $0.105498$.

An alternative approach, that is not as elegant as the answer of Henry, is to attack the problem with combinatorics.
The probability will be expressed as
$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{52}{13} \times \binom{39}{13} \times \binom{26}{13} = \frac{52!}{(13!)^4}.$$
In computing $~D,~$ I am assuming that the 4 players are distinguishable from each other.  So, I will have to make the same assumption when computing $~N.~$
When computing $~N,~$ it is as if there are two separate decks: one deck has 4 cards, which are the $~4~$ Aces, and the second deck has the other $~48~$ cards.
So, the number of ways of dealing $~13~$ cards to the first player is $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{48}{12}.$
Then, the number of ways of dealing $~13~$ cards to the second player is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{36}{12}.$
Then, the number of ways of dealing $~13~$ cards to the third player is $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{24}{12}.$
Then, the fourth player automatically gets the remaining cards.
Therefore,
$$N = 4! \times \frac{48!}{(12!)^4}.$$
So, the final computation is
$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{4! \times (48!) \times (13!)^4}{(52!) \times (12!)^4}$$
$$= \frac{4! \times (13)^4}{52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49}$$
$$= \frac{52 \times 39 \times 26 \times 13}{52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49}.$$
